# Check if cookies are enabled on mobile device (Chrome on iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a website which requires some session cookies. It works fine, but today one user got error because he was allowed to access url without allowing cookies.

This is how I check for cookies:

```
function areCookiesEnabled(modal)
{
  if(!navigator.cookieEnabled)
  {
    alert("Cookies are disabled")
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    $('#'+modal).modal();
  }
}
```

And:

```
<button onclick="areCookiesEnabled('exampleModal')" class="btn btn-success"> Open </button>
```

He uses Chrome on iOS device. For Safari on iOS it works fine.

What could be the reason that this doesn't work for Chrome?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Does it report that they're enabled when they aren't, or report that they're disabled when they are?

Comment: I'd check credibility of the user first...

Comment: Is he really blocking all cookies, or just third-party cookies?

Comment: @Barmar He is not getting the data which should be in session (cookie). That's why I suspected that it might be a problem with not allowing cookies. Like I said for Safari works fine, for Chrome doesn't. Then I added this function to check if cookies are allowed and it returns `true` somehow.

Comment: It might not be relevant, but have you read the first note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/cookieEnabled? It describes a difference between Safari/Edge/IE and Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: And the next note defines another Chrome restriction.